# Should I do anything to make my code more pythonic?

Tags: python

This is a very simple piece of code that I wrote but if there is a way to make it more pythonic then I would love to know.  Thanks!

```
def money():
    current_salary = float(input("What is your current salary? "))
    years = int(input("How many years would you like to look ahead? ")) + 1
    amount_of_raise = float(input("What is the average percentage raise you think you will get? "))
    amount_of_raise = amount_of_raise * 0.01

    while years > 1:
        years = years - 1
        new_salary = current_salary + (current_salary * amount_of_raise)
        current_salary = new_salary
        print('Looks like you will be making', new_salary,' in ', years,'years.')

money()
```

Comment: You can make use of `*=` and `-=` operators

Comment: The first thing that jumps out to me is that `money` is not a very informative name. What the heck does this function even do? Pick a better name, and maybe give it a docstring while you're at it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about coding style rather than solving a specific problem. It may be migrated to another StackExchange site (CodeReview). You don't have to delete it or anything, but be sure to check a site's FAQ before posting next time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code-review (and thus should be at http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Instead of using a `while` loop and decrementing `years` on each iteration, use a `for` loop over an appropriate `range`. Using a `while` for this loop is uglier and bug-prone - in fact, your loop has an off-by-one bug.

Comment: No problem guys.  I was not aware of code review but I'll use that next time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Extended assignment operators

```
amount_of_raise = amount_of_raise * 0.01
years = years - 1
```

`x = x * y` can be shortened to `x *= y`. Same thing for `-`.

```
amount_of_raise *= 0.01
years -= 1
```

#### Iteration and counting

```
while years > 1:
    years = years - 1
```

Counting down causes your printouts to display backwards. I would count up. The Pythonic way to count uses `range`:

```
for year in range(1, years + 1):
    print('Looks like you will be making', new_salary,' in ', years,'years.')
```

#### Computing new salary

```
new_salary = current_salary + (current_salary * amount_of_raise)
current_salary = new_salary
```

I'd probably just simplify that to:

```
current_salary += current_salary * amount_of_raise
```

Or even better is to give a 5% raise by multiplying by 1.05. In code that is:

```
current_salary *= 1 + amount_of_raise
```

Comment: I believe you mean `current_salary *= 1 + amount_of_raise`.